# Как получить компоненту вектора в sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy.vector import *
base = CoordSys3D('base')
x = 2* base.i + 3*base.j
x.components
```

Как получить? Каждую компоненту отдельно.

```
x.components -
```

не дает их отдельно.

Нужны значения. 2 и 3 в данном случае/

Comment: в каком виде вы хотите их получить?

Comment: поправил в шапке

Answer (score 3):

`x.components` - возвращает словарь. Соответственно мы можем работать с ним **как с обычным словарем**:

```
In [40]: components = [{k:v} for k,v in x.components.items()]

In [41]: components[0]
Out[41]: {base.i: 2}

In [42]: components[1]
Out[42]: {base.j: 3}
```

---

```
In [43]: list(x.components.values())
Out[43]: [2, 3]
```

---

```
In [68]: x.components[base.i]
Out[68]: 2

In [69]: x.components[base.j]
Out[69]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ -

```
x.components.get(base.i)
x.components.get(base.j)
```